# Why does my Celsius/Fahrenheit converter function always return 0?

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a Celsius/Fahrenheit converter function.

```
fn main(){
    println!("{}", convert_temp("c", 100)); //Boiling point to F
    println!("{}", convert_temp("f", 77)); //Room temperature
}
fn convert_temp(from: &str, temp: i32) -> i32{
    let result = 0;
    if from == "c"{
        let result = (temp * (9/5)) + 32;
    } else if from == "f"{
        let result = (temp - 32) * (5/9);
    }
    result
}
```

Regardless of the value of `from`, the function always returns 0. There are no errors. I printed the value of from to check it was what I expected and I didn't see anything wrong. I also tried changing `if from == "c"` to `if from == String::from("c")` but that did nothing. How do I make the comparison work?

Comment: The "let result" in the if blocks are new variables sheltering the one before. Omit the"let" and fix the line comparing to "f".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've changed `let result = 0` to `let mut result = 0` and I've removed the let from within the if blocks. Now I get an output of 312 and 0, both of which are incorrect. Any idea why?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097710/dividing-two-integers-doesnt-print-as-a-decimal-number-in-rust

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, that fixed it. Is there a better way to do this than adding a redundant `.0` to every single integer?

Comment: No, there's no more concise way of writing float literals than by including their fractional part (even if zero)—but maintainers of your code (including your future self!) will be grateful that integer and float literals are so clearly distinguished/not easily confused.

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know

Comment: Actually, you can just use a trailing dot (e.g. `5.`), which may even be considered the convention.

Comment: @Coder-256 That's good to know, thank you

Comment: "The "let result" in the if blocks are new variables sheltering the one before." - I meant "shadowing", not "sheltering" :D damn autocompletion on phone...

Comment: @Henry every "trivial fix" that an answerer has to do makes it less likely that they will answer. And if it's trivial, then it's equally trivial to fix beforehand. And _any_ fix that the answerer has to make to reproduce the problem might be something different from your original code, wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for you that would make this work, but also be much more clear to debug:

#### Instead of setting `0` as the default value, use an `Option`

This way, you can set the default as `None`.

Why is this beneficial?
Because it allows you to see whether or not the result comes from one of the branches being evaluated, or if the result is simply the default.

#### Use floats

One of your calculations (for Fahreinheit -> Celsius) was always returning `0` because (I suspect) `5/9` does not cleanly divide.

#### Make the result mutable with `let mut`, and remove the `let` from the branches

Your code was re-declaring the `result` variable inside each `if` branch.
This value was not available to the upper scope. The original variable on the first line of the function body was not being mutated, and it was immutable anyway.

#### Example code with fixes

```rust
fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", convert_temp("c", 100.0)); //Boiling point to F
    println!("{:?}", convert_temp("f", 100.0)); //Room temperature
}
fn convert_temp(from: &str, temp: f32) -> Option<f32>{
    let mut result = None;
    if from == "c" {
        result = Some((temp * (9.0/5.0)) + 32.0);
    } else if from == "f" {
        result = Some((temp - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0));
    }
    result
}
```

You can possibly remove the `Option` result type later on once you are happy with how the function works and have guaranteed that it will return a correct result. In the meantime, it should help you debug the program.

Comment: You could just do away with the `result` variable altogether.

Comment: Moreover, a better design overall would probably be to define `struct Celsius(f32)` and `struct Fahrenheit(f32)` and impl `From` for conversions in each direction.

Comment: I agree, that's worth putting as an alternative answer

Answer (score 2):

The better alternative for your program is here a `match` statement: it is shorter, succinct, prevents nonsense input eg. `"x"` and avoids your sort of error.
I would leave the complexity of the input vality check to the caller of `convert_temp()`.

```
fn convert_temp(from: &str, temp: f32) -> f32 {
    match from {
        "c" => temp * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0,
        "f" => (temp - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0),
        _   => todo!(),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=267d022de56e2a8e650a7b4ad55d5fc1)